# presenting repeating column values as blanks in query results except for the very first row in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I edited my question:

I get an Invalid object name '#Temp1'. The code below runs in a cursor loop...

Code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL
                BEGIN
                    DROP TABLE #Temp1
                END

                    Insert Into #Temp1 
                    Select o.EventSetName,
                           o.EventSetDisplay,
                           o.EventSetDescription,
                           o.ChildSetName,
                           ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By o.ChildSetName) RN                  
                    From   ##ObsSetLevel o,
                           ##Final f
                    Where  f.ChildSetName = o.EventSetName and 
                           o.EventSetName = @ObsSetList 
                    Order By o.ChildSetName asc  

                    Insert into ##Final
                    Select *
                    From #Temp1
                    Where  RN = 1
                    Union
                    Select '', '', '', ChildSetName, RN
                    From #Temp1
                    Where RN > 1
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: yep..i completely agree..whenever I need any inner joins I end up using the old style join....

Answer (score 2):

Remove the 't' from:

```
Into #Temp  t
```

So:

```
INTO #Temp
```

An alias is not allowed with `INTO`

I'd also recommend abandoning deprecated implicit joins:

```
SELECT  o.EventSetName,
        o.EventSetDisplay,
        o.EventSetDescription,
        o.ChildSetName,
        ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By o.ChildSetName) RN
INTO #Temp 
FROM    ##ObsSetLevel o
JOIN    ##Final f
    ON  f.ChildSetName = o.EventSetName 
        AND o.EventSetName = @ObsSetList 
ORDER By o.ChildSetName asc
```